# Display one element from list in Flutter

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart

I'm pretty newbie in the coding world and I need some help.

How can I get one element from a list and display it.
I will wrap this in a Text widget and I need it to change to the next element in the list onTap.
When it reach the end of the list I need to go back to the first element.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. It would be better if you include what things you have done so far.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further details on how to improve your question. Including the code you have t the moment is key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are looking for correctly, the following example should do what you want:

```
class ItemList65565217 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ItemList65565217State createState() => _ItemList65565217State();
}

class _ItemList65565217State extends State<ItemList65565217> {
  List<String> _itemList = [
    'item 1',
    'item 2',
    'item 3',
    'item 4',
    'item 5',
    'item 6',
  ];

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text(_itemList[_currentIndex]),
          onPressed: nextItem,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void nextItem(){
    setState(() {
      if(_currentIndex == _itemList.length -1){
        _currentIndex = 0;
      }else{
        _currentIndex++;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still struggling to make it work but at least now I have a point where to start.

Comment: What are you struggling with?

Comment: @shortnightss were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Hello @João Soares! Unfortunately I'm still trying to solve the problem.